# Apply strptime to data.frame

Tags: r, apply, strptime

I have a data.frame object which contains separate columns for year, month, and day.  i want to convert this into one column of POSIXlt type objects. so my data.frame look like

```
test_df <- data.frame(matrix(data = as.integer(c(1900,1900,1900,1,1,1,1,2,3)), 
                             nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
colnames(test_df) <- c("Year","Month","Day")
```

if i try to convert an individual row in the following manner

```
paste(test_df$Year[1], test_df$Month[1], test_df$Day[1], sep = "/") %>%
as.factor() %>% 
strptime(format = "%Y/%m/%d")
```

i end up with a POSIXlt class object.  however if i try to use an apply function such as this

```
test_df$date <- apply(test_df, 1, 
                      function(x) 
                      strptime(as.factor(paste(x[1], x[2], x[3], 
                                         sep = "/")), 
                               format = "%Y/%m/%d"))
```

i end up getting list objects in that new column.  What can i do to maintain the POSIXlt class while using apply?

Comment: `strptime(paste(test_df$Year, test_df$Month, test_df$Day, sep = "/"), format = "%Y/%m/%d")`

Comment: Or similar to Ronak's, `strptime(do.call(paste, test_df), format = '%Y %m %d')`

Answer (score 1):

It is better practice to use `POSIXct` instead of `POSIXlt` in data frames. The following should do the same job:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- test_df %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(paste(Year, Month, Day), format = "%Y %m %d"))

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
#   $ Year : int  1900 1900 1900
# $ Month: int  1 1 1
# $ Day  : int  1 2 3
# $ date : POSIXct, format: "1900-01-01" "1900-01-02" "1900-01-03"
```

Comment: slight modification using `lubridate`
`df <- test_df %>% 
  mutate(date = parse_date_time(paste(Year, Month, Day), "y m d"))`

Comment: why is it better to use POSIXct instead of POSIXlt in data frames?

Comment: @VictorMaxwell; their structure is not ideal for data frames. [This post](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/179#issuecomment-32591502) should give a better intuition.